# R pairwise.adonis2 for post hoc test of 2-way PERMANOVA

Tags: r, posthoc, two-way

I’m trying to do post-hoc test for two-way permanova using pairwise.adonis2 in R with the following syntax:

```
pairwise.adonis2(community ~ factorA, data = data, strata = “factorB”)
```

But the results only show the overall effect of factorA (with the effect of factorB controlled I believe), rather than showing the effect of factor A at each level of factorB. Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: Hi this look more like an one-way PERMANOVA with a block in permutations than a two-way test.